# Partially Sophisticated Quasi-Hyperbolic Discounting Problem

Tags: discount-rate, intertemporal-choice, discount, game-theory

I am trying to follow the bottom method for partially sophisticated hyperbolic discounting...

[image]

The setup (modified from an earlier problem in the same course) is that a person will get different "instantaneous utilities" $u_0, u_1, u_2, u_3$ from watching a movie in one of multiple time periods (perhaps based on who she can watch it with, whether popcorn will be available, etc.).  Given that it is now time $t_0$, I think the game tree should look something like this...

[image]

The problem is that the instructions say to use $\beta$ in the first period (I assume this and "period 1" refer to my $t_0$), but in quasi-hyperbolic discounting, there is no discounting in the first period.  Discounting with $\beta$ at $t_1$ instead doesn't make sense to me, because the agent will believe her $t_1$ self discounts with $\hat\beta$.  How should this game tree look at time $t_0$, and how should I then evolve it to time $t_1$?